# Declare a SQL Cursor into With-As Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio which have a with clause.

And I want use a SQL cursor in with clause.

My stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllCandidatesEmployeesByOrgId]            
   @ip_OrgId as int,             
   @Active_XML as Bit 

WITH q AS
(
  SELECT 
     'Candidate' AS [Entity]        
     ,viwProposals.ProposalId AS EntityID  
     ,viwProposals.LastModifiedOn AS LastModifiedOn 
  FROM 
     viwProposals 
  WHERE 
     OrgId=@ip_OrgId  AND IsHide = 0

  UNION

  SELECT 
    'Employee' AS [Entity]          
    ,viwEmployees.EmployeeId AS EntityID
    ,viwEmployees.LastModifiedOn AS LastModifiedOn
  FROM 
     viwEmployees 
  WHERE 
     OrgId=@ip_OrgId AND IsTerminate = 0
  )
  SELECT  
      q.*, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LastModifiedOn DESC) AS RowNo
  FROM    
      q              
  ORDER BY 
      LastModifiedOn DESC               
END
```

I want to run cursor on `q` how can I do this.

Comment: ***WHY*** on earth do you want to use a cursor? That's the **worst** possible design in most cases in a SQL Server context - **don't do it** unless you **absolutely** have to....

Comment: What error you are getting ? Also we can see that IsHide is not defined anywhere in this SP and you are using in where cluase WHERE 
     OrgId=@ip_OrgId  AND IsHide = @IsHide

Comment: ip_OrgId is a parameter which pass when call store procedure (for example ip_OrgId = 400) and IsHide is a variable (for example IsHide = 0) - @Sandeep Kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllCandidatesEmployeesByOrgId]

   @ip_OrgId INT,             
   @Active_XML BIT 

AS BEGIN

    DECLARE 
          @Entity VARCHAR(10)
        , @EntityID BIGINT
        , @LastModifiedOn DATETIME
        , @RowNum BIGINT

    DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
        SELECT  
              q.Entity
            , q.EntityID
            , q.LastModifiedOn
            , RowNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY q.LastModifiedOn DESC) 
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                  'Candidate' AS [Entity]        
                , v.ProposalId AS EntityID  
                , v.LastModifiedOn AS LastModifiedOn 
            FROM dbo.viwProposals  v
            WHERE OrgId=@ip_OrgId  AND IsHide = 0

            UNION

            SELECT 
                  'Employee'         
                , v.EmployeeId
                , v.LastModifiedOn
            FROM dbo.viwEmployees v 
            WHERE OrgId=@ip_OrgId AND IsTerminate = 0
        ) q             
        ORDER BY LastModifiedOn DESC

    OPEN cursor_name

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO 
          @Entity
        , @EntityID
        , @LastModifiedOn
        , @RowNum

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

        --

        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO 
              @Entity
            , @EntityID
            , @LastModifiedOn
            , @RowNum

    END

    CLOSE cursor_name;
    DEALLOCATE cursor_name;

END
```

Or try this -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllCandidatesEmployeesByOrgId]

   @ip_OrgId INT,             
   @Active_XML BIT 

AS BEGIN

    DECLARE 
          @Entity VARCHAR(10)
        , @EntityID BIGINT
        , @LastModifiedOn DATETIME
        , @RowNum BIGINT

    DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
        WITH cte AS 
        (
            SELECT 
                  'Candidate' AS [Entity]        
                , v.ProposalId AS EntityID  
                , v.LastModifiedOn AS LastModifiedOn 
            FROM dbo.viwProposals  v
            WHERE OrgId=@ip_OrgId  AND IsHide = 0

            UNION

            SELECT 
                  'Employee'         
                , v.EmployeeId
                , v.LastModifiedOn
            FROM dbo.viwEmployees v 
            WHERE OrgId=@ip_OrgId AND IsTerminate = 0
        )
        SELECT  
              q.Entity
            , q.EntityID
            , q.LastModifiedOn
            , RowNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY q.LastModifiedOn DESC) 
        FROM cte q             
        ORDER BY LastModifiedOn DESC

    OPEN cursor_name

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO 
          @Entity
        , @EntityID
        , @LastModifiedOn
        , @RowNum

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

        --

        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO 
              @Entity
            , @EntityID
            , @LastModifiedOn
            , @RowNum

    END

    CLOSE cursor_name;
    DEALLOCATE cursor_name;

END
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i want to update "cte q " into cursor. It is possible?

Comment: Sorry, but CTE is not a table. So short answer is no.